# How do I stop my page from lagging when all sections of a div are visible?

Tags: html, jquery, css

My HTML file is 2845 lines long. And the main content is around 1523 lines long.
My content is lagging when I scroll between the contents. The file gets stuck.
It also has a select tag which helps in easy navigation between the contents. When option A is selected section A will be displayed, option B will display section B, and, option C will display both sections A & B.
This is just an example, the main page has 12 such options.

So is there any way to stop the lag?

I have put all those sections in different div so that they can be viewed on the basis of the option selected.

Comment: I added a Simple demo , you can see it in my answer

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do, is adding "display:none" to the elements.

display: none , hides the element and destroys its rendering state. This means unhiding the element is as expensive as rendering a new element with the same contents.

Then you can use the "scrollTop()" and "offset().top" methods to render it back into the DOM.

Here is an example of what i told you :

```js
window.onscroll = function () { scrollFunction() };
        function scrollFunction() {
            var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
                boxesOffset[i] = boxes[i].offsetTop;
                boxesOffsetHeight[i] = boxes[i].offsetHeight;
            }
            boxSize = boxesOffsetHeight[toWitchBox] + nextScrollTop
            console.log(boxSize + " , " + toWitchBox)
            if ((scrollTop > boxSize) && toWitchBox < boxes.length - 1) {
                boxes[toWitchBox + 1].style.display = "block";
                nextScrollTop = scrollTop
                toWitchBox += 1
            }
        }
        var nextScrollTop = 0
        var toWitchBox = 0
        var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
        var boxesOffsetHeight = []
        var boxesOffset = []
```

```css
 body {
            min-height: 5200px;
        }

        #box1 {
            background-color: red;
            width: 800px;
            height: 600px;
        }

        #box2 {
            background-color: yellow;
            width: 800px;
            height: 800px;
            display: none;
        }

        #box3 {
            background-color: blue;
            width: 800px;
            display: none;
            height: 800px;
        }

        #box4 {
            background-color: green;
            width: 800px;
            display: none;
            height: 800px;
        }

        #box5 {
            background-color: pink;
            width: 800px;
            display: none;
            height: 800px;
        }
```

```html
<body>


    <div id="box1" class="box">

    </div>
    <div id="box2" class="box">

    </div>
    <div id="box3" class="box">

    </div>
    <div id="box4" class="box">

    </div>

    <div id="box5" class="box">

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: When the page loads only section A is visible. All other sections are hidden.

When section B is visible section A will hide (display: none;).

But there is a command C to make sections A & B visible. And since section A & B have separate scrollbar I need to change the display to "inline" to make it such that only one scrollbar is there for the whole section.

Comment: But then the page gets stuck and its not responding.

Comment: How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you please tell how to use the "scrollTop()" function to solve this?

Comment: The problem is that window is stuck (PAGE NOT RESPONDING) when the display of all section goes to inline.